# Getting a count of action from today's date from filtered results in Python

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have an action that a user can do many times a day. I'm trying to get a count of how many times the user has taken that action, but only for today's date. Here's the way I'm currently solving this, but is there an easier way?  I feel like I should be able to fit this in one line. :)

```
today_slaps = 0
slaps = Slap.objects.filter(from_user=request.user.id)
for slap in slaps:
    if slap.date.date() == datetime.now().date():
        today_slaps += 1
```

The logic I'm looking for is:

```
slaps = Slap.objects.filter(from_user=2, date.date()=datetime.now().date()).count()
```

But that's obviously throwing an error that a keyword can't be an expression. Sorry if this is a basic one, but thoughts?

Comment: Are you really making an application to track how many times you slap people? :)

Comment: It's going to take over the world  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
slap_count = Slap.objects.filter(from_user=request.user, \ 
                      date__gte=datetime.date.today()).count()

# specifically setting datetimefield=datetime.date.today() won't work
# gte = will work for datetimefield vs datetime object starting at that date
# it's also assumed there will never be a slap from the future.
```

Generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... date >= 2011-02-26 00:00:00
```

So it's safe to say you will only get today's slaps, again, unless you have slaps from the future. If you do, I'd set every `date__day, date__year, date__month` explicitly.

Comment: The above is giving a method_descriptor error, but when i move date after today, it works brilliantly. Thanks... What I'm using: slap_count = Slap.objects.filter(from_user=3, date__gte=datetime.today().date()).count()

Comment: Hey Brenden, right, that's because I `import datetime`, not `from datetime import datetime`, to get access to methods like `datetime.date.today()`. Please accept if it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Yuji](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131384/getting-a-count-of-action-from-todays-date-from-filtered-results-in-python/5131395#5131395) (below) we came up with this answer:

```
slap_count = Slap.objects.filter(from_user=request.user.id, date__gte=datetime.today().date()).count()
```